# How do I inherit from prog-mode, whilst still supporting older emacsen?

Tags: major-mode, prog-mode, version-compatibilty

I'm writing a major mode for a programming language, but I want to support older Emacs versions. `prog-mode` is relatively new. I want to inherit from `prog-mode` if it's defined, but still do something sensible otherwise.

What's the best approach? Should I `defalias` `prog-mode` on older Emacsen, or will that interfere with other modes if they do the same thing?

Comment: I'd advice to simply drop support for Emacs < 24.  In my opinion it is not worth the effort anymore, and you'll have to waive more important features than `prog-mode`.  Notably, you'll suffer from the lack of lexical binding.

Comment: I'm contributing to julia-mode, and some of the core team use older Emacsen and would prefer we supported it.

Comment: @lunaryorn Emacs 24 is still pretty new. Emacs 23 is the current version on many OSes. Emacs 22 is still current on a few. Not everyone upgrades their software like crazy. Dropping support for Emacs 23 would limit you to the few users who crave the bleeding edge.

Comment: There are many reasons to use older Emacs versions. For example, on Windows, Emacs 23 became really sluggish, so I have opted to stick to Emacs 22 there.

Comment: @Gilles I doubt that it's just a "few users".  Flycheck never supported Emacs 23 in the first place, and became one of the most popular packages on MELPA nonetheless…

Comment: lunaryorn: Sure, but ELPA was third-party functionality for Emacs 23, and a great many people would never have encountered that library. I suspect your observation only indicates that more people are using packages with the major version of Emacs which supports them out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the cost of an extra top-level symbol binding, there's a very neat solution which avoids repeating the `define-derived-mode` form:

```
(defalias 'my-fancy-parent-mode
  (if (fboundp 'prog-mode) 'prog-mode 'fundamental-mode))

(define-derived-mode my-fancy-mode my-fancy-parent-mode
   ...)
```

Works fine in any Emacs >= 23. I came up with this for `haml-mode` a couple of years ago IIRC, and it seems to have spread from there to several other major modes. The main thing the `define-derived-mode` macro does with the parent mode symbol is generate code which calls its function: in this sense, `defalias` makes the new variable exactly equivalent to the aliased function.

One caveat is that this can confuse `derived-mode-p`, so code which checks to see if your mode is derived from `prog-mode` might not work correctly. In practice I haven't encountered any problems: it's more usual for such code to hook into `prog-mode-hook`, which still gets run.

(As Jorgen points out in the comments, `define-derived-mode` also uses the `mode-class` property from the parent mode symbol, and `defalias` will not copy it. At the time of writing, this property [only seems to be used for `special-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Major-Modes.html).)

*Update: these days I'd simply suggest requiring at least Emacs 24, since older versions are long obsolete.*

Comment: Nice solution! Just a caveat: This works for `prog-mode`, but will not work for every mode. `define-derived-mode` copies the `mode-class` symbol property to the child mode. The `defalias` will _not_ transfer this property. If `mode-class` is relevant to your use case, you need to copy/set it manually.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, Jorgen -- I'll have to dig around and learn more about what the `mode-class` property denotes.

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr: Use `if` and your own init function:

```
(if (fboundp 'prog-mode)
    (define-derived-mode your-cool-mode prog-mode "Cool"
      "Docstring"
      (your-cool--init))
  (define-derived-mode your-cool-mode nil "Cool"
    "Docstring"
    (your-cool--init)))
```

Then do all the mode's initialization in `your-cool-init`.

Longer explanation:

The problem is that the official way of writing a derived major mode is to use the `define-derived-mode` macro:

```
(define-derived-mode your-cool-mode prog-mode ...)
```

On older Emacsen (pre-24), this breaks when `prog-mode`. And you can't use `(if (fboundp 'prog-mode) ...)` there because the macro expects a literal symbol, and will quote it for you in the expansion.

`define-derived-mode` uses the parent in a multitude of ways. You'd need to copy all of those in your own mode definition to make use of them, and that's both tedious and error-prone.

So the only way is to use two different `define-derived-mode` statements, depending on whether `prog-mode` exists or not. That leaves you with the problem of writing your initialization code twice. Which is of course bad, so you extract that into its own function, as described above.

(The best solution is of course to drop support for 23.x and use lexical scoping. But I guess you already considered and dropped that option. :-))

Comment: What's the closest equivalent to `prog-mode` in older Emacsen? Would it make sense to derive from `text-mode` or `fundamental-mode` if `prog-mode` isn't available?

Comment: @Jorgen Or can we derive an intermediate mode using `fboundp` first, with just the `define-derived-mode` statement? Then the actual mode with full definition can be derived from that intermediate mode? That way the whole mode doesn't have to be defined twice.

Comment: @WilfredHughes, there is none. Deriving from `fundamental-mode` is equivalent to deriving from `nil` (and indeed, `define-derived-mode` replaces `fundamental-mode` with `nil`), while `text-mode` is not appropriate, as program code is not text. Most of the default settings in `text-mode` do not make sense in programming modes outside of comments. This is why `prog-mode` was introduced in Emacs 24.

Comment: @kaushalmodi, you could derive an intermediate mode, but that would still require two `define-derived-mode` definitions in an `if` form, just for the intermediate mode instead of the final mode. You would be replacing the `defun` for the init function with a `define-derived-mode` for the final mode. I do not think this is particularly preferable.

You could also define a `prog-mode` yourself, as the original question suggests, but that can easily confuse other modes who rely on `fboundp` to check for the presence of that mode.

Comment: I don't believe that two different `define-derived-mode` statements are necessary. A couple of years ago I came up with the solution I've posted as a separate answer, and it seems to work fine in both Emacs 23 & 24. Code like it is used in a number of popular major modes.

Comment: Nice solution, @sanityinc! Thanks, I learned something today :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think testing using `fboundp` makes more sense.

```
(if (fboundp 'prog-mode)
    ...
   ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a wrapper macro for `define-derived-mode` that evaluates its arguments.

```
(defmacro define-derived-mode* (child parent name &optional docstring &rest body)
  (macroexpand `(define-derived-mode ,(eval child) ,(eval parent) ,(eval name)
                                     ,(eval docstring) . ,body)))
(define-derived-mode* 'toy-mode
  (if (fboundp 'prog-mode) 'prog-mode 'fundamental-mode)
  "Toy"
  "Major mode for my favorite toy language"
  (toy-mode-setup))
```

(Warning: only minimally tested.)